# What parts of cordova cli generated projects can be safely versioned in source control?

Tags: version-control, cordova

I'm looking to use [Cordova CLI](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli) instead of a home grown ant solution for command line management of a phonegap/cordova project.  I'm wondering what parts of the directory tree, if any, should not be placed under version control?

Comment: If you are looking for a 2015 up to date answer,check http://stackoverflow.com/a/31477347/82609

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends on you project and your workflow.

For a lot of projects, the `./www` folder would be sufficient as already mentioned, however there are some other folders that could be good to have depending on what aspects of the cli you are using.

Examples:

- `./merges` for platform specific  HTML/CSS/JS overrides
- `./.cordova` for cli hooks (like before_build, after_plugin_add, etc)

Plus anything else custom you might want to keep out of `./www` during development. For example, I have a `./src` folder and the contents are concatenated and added to `./www` as part of our build process. Our unit tests are also outside of `./www`.

Instead of including a specific folder, I have a `.gitignore` that keeps build artefacts like `./platforms/*` and `./plugins/*` out of version control.

Comment: I expanded on this answer based on my experience over the past few months in a sample chapter of my book: https://leanpub.com/developingwithcordovacli/read#leanpub-auto-version-control

Comment: In your ebook ( https://leanpub.com/developingwithcordovacli/read#leanpub-auto-version-control ), you say "There is also a .cordova directory in your home directory that you should not version control". It sounds to me as though your saying there are multiple .cordova files, and some should be in version control, while others should not. Could you please make this a little clearer?  For instance, I am using windows, and there is a directory `C:\Users\Deltahost\.corodova` is that the one your referring to for exclusion? I would'nt normally put my user directory on git anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why `plugins` and certain parts of `platform` should be ignored? Let's say I have some modifications needed in `AndroidManifest.xml`? `plugins` I just plain don't understand. Are the plugins stored somewhere else so that when a you build that directory gets populated?

Comment: If you're .gitignoring plugins/*, how do you initialize this directory after cloning it for the first time?

Comment: Just include (and commit) a `.gitignore` file in your empty plugins dir when setting up initially. This keeps the folder in git.

Comment: Recent versions of cordova have a separate folder named 'hooks', it may no longer be necessary to add '.cordova' folder under version control

Comment: as @blockhead I don't really understand weither or not I should add platform to my git repo, because it contains the android manifest that I should probably add to my git repo as the default generated one does not fit...

Comment: if i dont add platforms then how is cordova suppose to know which platforms is configured to?

Answer (score 14):

**2015 - Cordova 5.1.1 answer**

After working for some time with a Cordova project from 3.4.0 to 5.1.1, here's my feedback!

My `.gitignore` file looks like:

```
*~
**~
platforms/**
plugins/**
```

The `www` / `.cordova` and other folders you need are versionned.

My `.cordova` folder is currently empty (I used to have some errors when no `.cordova` folder, maybe it's not the case anymore)

All the plugins and platforms should be registered into the `config.xml` file.

If you add plugins by command line, use `cordova plugin add $pluginName --save --shrinkwrap` -> it will add the plugin automatically to `config.xml` and fix the version number, making the Cordova project easier to share among developers.

[Read more](http://www.gorkem-ercan.com/2014/06/sharing-cordova-projects-becomes-easier.html) about it and about sharing cordova projects, by the feature author.

Having the plugins in `config.xml` permits the plugins to be installed on other developer computers when they install a platform. Without that they will need to add themselves the plugin.

Somehow the `config.xml` acts like a `package.json` for NPM projects. But I still don't know how to handle a new plugin added, as far as I know the plugins are only installed during platform installation, there's no `npm insall/update` equivalent (but you can uninstall/reinstall the platform).

Here's an example `config.xml` from my project:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="co.xxx" version="0.2.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>
        Your Knowledge Network
    </description>
    <author email="info@xxx.co" href="https://xxx.co">
        xxx
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="1.2.0" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^3.6.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^1.0.1" />
</widget>
```

The platforms do not get automatically installed (as far as I know), but at least when an user install the platform, he'll get the right platform version!

Some other people are using [Plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman), a tool intended to manage Cordova plugins (not tested yet).

Comment: You can run `cordova prepare` in order to install missing plugins listed in config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Well what u control is your own choise, although, I would personaly only use version-control on the `www folder`, since is where all your coding and stored content is ( `html, css, js, images, audio, etc` ), all the rest will be static content (in most of the cases)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't add only a comment, so here's my reply for @blockhead and Sebastien Lorber:

It is not necessary to save files from folder 'platform' even file 'AndroidManifest.xml' (or any configuration file for other platform). **You can specify your preferences in 'config.xml' and it will affects these generated platform specific configuration files** (e.g. AndroidManifest) - see [phonegap documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics).

Then **you can have under version control only folder 'www' and file 'config.xml'.**

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this, but I think it depends on the attribute of AndroidManifest.xml that you want to modify.  Some are configurable via config.xml, and some are not.

Comment: in current cordova there is options that can be added to config.xml that modifies `AndroidManifest.xml`, use that instead, and that would solve @mooreds issue

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to code of Cordova CLI android platform centered (Android Hybrid complex project) into subversion then these files can be excluded while developing with team:

```
// to exclude files into repo
.gitignore
.gradle
.idea
local.properties
android.iml

/build
/gradlew
/gradlew.bat
/gradle

CordovaLib/CordovaLib.iml
```

If anyone is having problems with an svn error while import project of Gradle option from disk only not inbuilt subversion client of android studio then the following link will be helpful to you:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/34633162/5287727

Answer (score 0):

I have been a cordova dev since v2.9 and the typical advice of excluding the platform and plugin folders works most of the time.... except for when it doesn't.

I have noticed on a project that feels like it uses every plugin known to man that this mantra has broken down, and I am unable to easily go back and forth in version control and reliably produce a new build.

This is for a few reasons:

Apple changes things up, and as time goes along there are a number of cordova hacks that need to be added to a project to get it to be reliable. For example, iOS 10 added a requirement that if you use the camera, then you needed to specify what you were using it for - or the app would crash when you tried. While I was waiting for the camera plugin to fix this, I needed to edit the iOS source files, then some time later I needed to build an old version, and in crept the issues.

But the real pain is when plugins stray from the cordova way of doing things. This project I am referring to uses the Adobe Aviary / Image editing SDK. Their instructions are to install the plugin, copy over some sdk files downloaded separately, then install it again. I tried making a script that wouldn't kill it, but it has ended up just being that I now commit the plugins and platforms directory to the app - this way I can go back in time and reliably recreate a build.

Yes it adds more size to source control, yes I would love to do it "right", but it has bitten me hard. Just my $0.02

`TL/DR - When you starting working with more than a couple of plugins, you might need to consider adding the platforms and plugins folder to source control`

---

Update 2019-11-05

For the project I was referencing we have since made a commitment to just use things that integrate correctly, and now I believe it is better to not check platforms into source control at all. If the plugin doesn't work, the client should not be using it.

Cordova has also moved away from providing an upgrade path for platforms, instead requiring you to remove and add the platform again - this means that this workflow is the only way forward in my opinion.

Comment: If this is the case, consider using hooks instead to replace the relevant files on build