# Cordova Prepare/Build Unbinds WWW folder from Source Control (SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control, cordova

In my normal workflow, I am managing all code within the Cordova project's root "www" folder. When I am ready to deploy to a device/devices, I run the Cordova "cordova prepare" command which, to my knowledge, simply copies necessary assets to each platform's respective folders.

When doing this, the command interferes with SVN and removes the platform's "www" directory from source control. I assume this means the command deletes everything in this folder and replaces with root "www" contents, thus deleting the ".svn" folder which manages the source control information.

Does anyone know how I may prevent this from happening? I have heard and read a little about the Cordova "hooks" feature but have the slightest clue how that would work, nor how to accomplish a "hook" to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mooreds, thank you for being the only one to respond to my first Stack Overflow question! However, I have resolved this issue myself and will share my solution for others who may need it...

I decided to fork the Cordova CLI, analyze the code and see if I could come up with a solution.

It appears the primary files responsible for updating the specific platform's "www" directories is located in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/<platform>_parser.js` where `<platform>` is the name of the platform (ios, androind, etc...).

Most of the files have the same logic, so I will only post iOS...

The first issue...  within the `update_project` method, there is a `util.deleteSvnFolders(self.www_dir())` function call. As the name suggests, this was placed here to remove .svn folders from the project www directory. Probably because they were being copied in from source controlled root www but not wanted in the platform www folder. In my case, I still don't want the original .svn folders copied over, but I certainly don't want to delete them. Instead, don't copy them over to begin with and we wont have to delete them.

Below is the update_project method where I have commented out the method in question:

```
update_project:function(cfg, callback) {
    var self = this;
    this.update_from_config(cfg, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            if (callback) callback(err);
            else throw err;
        } else {
            self.update_www();
            self.update_overrides();
            self.update_staging();
            //util.deleteSvnFolders(self.www_dir());
            if (callback) callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Now the second part is within the `update_www` method just above that. This method uses `shell.rm` and `shell.cp` to remove the entire "www" directory, then copy the root "www" directory over into the project folder. The problem with this, of course, is that it removes all .svn folders and the "www" folder.

To solve this issue, enter `rsync`. rsync allows file copying at a much more robust level, in this case, allows us to exclude paths. So I modified these two lines into one operation with `rsync`:

```
update_www:function() {
    var projectRoot = util.isCordova(this.path);
    var www = util.projectWww(projectRoot);
    var project_www = this.www_dir();

    // Copy all files from root www to project www, excluding .svn directories.
    // rsync copies only files that are changed
    shell.exec("rsync -a --exclude='.svn/' " + www + "/ " + project_www);

    // write out proper cordova.js
    var custom_path = config.has_custom_path(projectRoot, 'ios');
    var lib_path = path.join(util.libDirectory, 'ios', 'cordova', require('../../platforms').ios.version);
    if (custom_path) lib_path = custom_path;
    shell.cp('-f', path.join(lib_path, 'CordovaLib', 'cordova.js'), path.join(project_www, 'cordova.js'));

}
```

The important part here is the `--exclude='.svn/'` option. This tells rsync to exclude items matching the --exclude='XXX'. In this case, `.svn/`. It's also worthy noting the forward slash after the `"www" + "/ "` which I added. This tells rsync to copy INTO the "www" folder, not the "www" folder itself. More exclude parameters can be used for other types, such as cvs or other version control files/folders.

Now, running `cordova prepare` copies only the needed files from the root "www" folder into each platform's "www" folders!

Another cool side-effect is that `rsync` copies only files that have changed by default. This means that check-ins are made via source control only to those files you changed, not the WHOLE directory due to a complete overwrite. Neato!

Other notes:

- Each `<platform>_parser.js` file handles this slightly different and names variables a little different. I am only targeting iOS and Android, so I didn't bother with the others.
- No, I did not bother with submitting the code to Cordova as I have no idea how and no time right now. Hopefully sharing the solution I came to here will balance out the Karma points I lose.

-Mike

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't place any files under `platforms` under version control.  For me, those directories are the province of Cordova CLI.

Here's a question about what should be version controlled: [What parts of cordova cli generated projects can be safely versioned in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989933/what-parts-of-cordova-cli-generated-projects-can-be-safely-versioned-in-source-c/)

And there's a bit more about version control in this sample of an ebook I'm writing: https://leanpub.com/developingwithcordovacli/read

If you have to version control `platforms`, I'd file a bug with the Cordova folks to ask them to please ignore dotfiles in directories under `platforms`: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB

Comment: Thanks for the response! Since the platform-specific projects are located within the platforms directory, it's critical for us to ensure they are under source control. In fact, since Cordova is the "project", the entire Cordova project should be (which is how we have it).

Comment: Update: I have taken a look at the resources you've provided. While I appreciate your view on those directories being "province of Cordova", my take would be that even though Cordova is it's own province, there is still a larger entity in control (SVN). Just like government! ;o)

I have done as you suggested and logged a bug report with Cordova. Although I am not going to hold my breath for any type of actual movement on their end... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4852

Comment: Have you seen any "Hooks" developed for this situation? I have looked but cannot find anything yet. We're in a major time crunch on this particular project so no time for that now, but as we move forward, going to need something. Thanks again for the helpful information!