# Where PhoneGap defines project directory?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

When I move my PhoneGap project to another folder, I can't run `phonegap local` commands anymore. For example, this command:

> phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git

results in this error:

> [error] project directory could not be found

My guess is that PhoneGap defines project directory somewhere in configuration and it can't find my project because I moved it to another folder. **I there a way to change PhoneGap project directory in configuration?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CLI tool create a new folder called ".cordova" for every project which is mostly hidden in some systems.

This folder is required for the folder to be identified as a phonegap project.

Comment: Still have issues, but it sees the project now. Thanks

Comment: you should run your commands from your actual project folder. Common mistake is that people try out of the project folder. use "cd folder" and try.

Comment: :) Ok. Here my problem (you've answered there already) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200998/failed-to-add-phonegap-plugin-due-to-syntax-error/20201097?noredirect=1#20201097

Comment: CLI is a new thing and its getting better in every version.

Answer (score 3):

The .cordova folder has a simple config.json file (did on mine), so you can copy it around with no trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is how PhoneGap defines the project directory:

- Has a *.cordova* directory, with a *config.json* inside.
- Has a *www* directory, with a *config.xml* inside.
- Has a *platforms* directory.

I found that with that in place you can use PhoneGap without issues. If you need an example for that config files just run `phonegap create myapp`.

Comment: Don't you mean the `.cordova` directory should have a `config.json` file inside?

Answer (score 1):

To complete other answers, this thread will help you understand what should be put in version control or not. The .cordova file should rather be versionned to avoid this kind of problems.

[What parts of cordova cli generated projects can be safely versioned in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989933/what-parts-of-cordova-cli-generated-projects-can-be-safely-versioned-in-source-c)

Answer (score 0):

you can use plugman 
npm install -g plugman

after it fot add plugin:
 plugman install --platform ios --project /YOUR/PROJECT/PATH/PATH/platforms/ios   --plugin /YOUR/PLUGIN/DIR/plugin1