# Failed to add PhoneGap plugin due to Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, cordova, syntax-error, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to add a plugin to my PhoneGap project and it fails with a Syntax Error.

Command:

> phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git

Executing:

> [phonegap] adding the plugin: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git

And then error:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/xcode/lib/parser/pbxproj.js:2654
>           throw new this.SyntaxError(
>                 ^
>   SyntaxError: Expected "/*", "=" or [A-Za-z0-9_] but "." found.

Looks like `node.js` parser throws an error because it encounter an unexpected `.`. Any ideas on **what causing it or how I can debug it further**?

Thanks;)

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling node as it worked for few as per the issue log.

Comment: No help. Works with a new empty project though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not alone, I guess :) Looks like a bug in CLI

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/188

Comment: Apparently was a bug which got fixed here https://github.com/alunny/node-xcode/commit/f69eb1715201b48919daa97388830e090e033793