# How can I add plugins to a Cordova app that was converted to Android Studio

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I have built a simple android app using Cordova which runs perfectly on a device.

I have a new requirement to alert the user on offline/online which I understand involves using the Network Information plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information).

Trying to add a plugin to the app using the CLI, as expected, I receive the error `Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.` because the project structure has changed.

How can I add this plugin into my app – manually if necessary?

I hope to not to have to resort to using eclipse again but will do if required.

Comment: How did you convert it to an Android Studio project? 
Could you just copy the /src/ and /js/ files over? 
Or maybe make a new CLI project, add all of the plugins and platforms that you have, then just copy those resources into your studio project folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created the project using 'cordova create ' from the command line, you'll have to recreate the project doing so to use the cordova plugin management.

Since I don't know the complexity of your application, I can't give you feedback on doing this.

It's best, if you want to use the cordova command line to manage plugins, to keep everything in the cordova structure in a version control system 
(see [What parts of cordova cli generated projects can be safely versioned in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989933/what-parts-of-cordova-cli-generated-projects-can-be-safely-versioned-in-source-c) for more).

Comment: I don't mind doing away with the CLI and manually integrating the plugins from source. That said I'm looking at creating a new app wrapper.

Comment: Ah.  If you are looking to integrate the plugins from source, you probably want to get familiar with plugman: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman