# Which files to ignore from source control for Visual Studio Apache Cordova apps (TACO)

Tags: cordova, version-control, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova, taco

I'm trying to find if there is a list of the files to ignore in source/version control for apache cordova apps built with visual studio version 2015.

There are a lot of files especially under platforms, and I'm not sure if they need to be included or not and if they will be re-generated if I clone my repository elsewhere.

Comment: At the moment i have got these files in my ignore list:  
_MyApp/bin/*  ,  
MyApp/platforms/*  ,  
MyApp/plugins/*_

Comment: The platform folders should be build artefacts, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989933/what-parts-of-cordova-cli-generated-projects-can-be-safely-versioned-in-source-c)

Comment: @Quintonn As far as i know, its safe to ignore only platforms folder. Its better to include plugins folder as some of the plugin updates may need re-testing of the app.

Comment: Agree. Platforms and plugins are build artefacts that don't need to be in source control. Generally only check in the files that you can modify (so make sure everything inside merges/ res/ www/ and config.xml and taco.json)